# SharePoint 2010 Excel Web Access "Automatically reloading workbook"

Tags: excel

I am working with SharePoint 2010. I used an Excel Web Access web part to display an Excel Spreadsheet. So that the spreadsheet can be opened in Excel and people can do editing.

However, every time when people save the changes and refresh the web page, the data in the excel spreadsheet won't be updated or reloaded. We have to manually click "File" --> "Reload Workbook".

I don't know if there is a way to do some sorts of "**Automatically reload the workbook when refreshing the page**". That is the major stuff I am looking for. I have been searching on the Internet. Seems like many people are asking the same stuff. But there is no any easy and clear solution.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Under your data connection you can set the refresh on open checkbox and you could also use the automatic timed refresh option.

[image]